# Hyperledger Error: Failed to connect to any peer event hubs. It is required that at least 1 event hub has been connected to receive the commit event

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger-composer

I'm facing the issue regarding creating and deploying a business network in Hyperledger Fabric. I've followed the official document to create and deploy it but I'm facing an issue while starting the business network. I'm stuck at this command.

```
$ composer network start --networkName ehr --networkVersion 0.0.3 --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --networkAdmin admin --networkAdminEnrollSecret adminpw --file networkadmin.card
```

The error message is:

```
    Processing these Network Admins: 
    userName: admin

✖ Starting business network definition. This may take a minute...
Error: Error trying to start business network. 
Error: Failed to connect to any peer event hubs. It is required that at least 1 event hub has been connected to receive the commit event
```

Comment: Hi, unfortunately Hyperledger Composer has been End of Life since August 2021. I would recommend switching to Hyperledger Fabric which has incorporated some of the ideas in Composer in recent versions.